# Can stream to Facebook using ffmpeg but not when using tee

Tags: facebook, ffmpeg

I'm trying to stream to YouTube and Facebook simultaneously using ffmpeg.

I can do them individually, but I want to use "tee" to send the results of encoding to two places.

If I do:

```
ffmpeg -re -i pipe:0 -acodec libfdk_aac -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc \
    -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline \
    -s 720x480 -bufsize 2048k -vb 1300k -maxrate 4000k -deinterlace \
    -vcodec libx264 -g 25 -r 25 \
    -f flv "rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/key"
```

It works just fine.

But if I do:

```
ffmpeg -re -i pipe:0 -acodec libfdk_aac -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc \
    -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline \
    -s 720x480 -bufsize 2048k -vb 1300k -maxrate 4000k -deinterlace \
    -vcodec libx264 -g 25 -r 25 \
    -f tee -map 0:v -map 0:a \
    "[f=flv]rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/key"
```

Then I get a rtmp 104 error.

If that would work then I could just do:

```
        "[f=flv]rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/key|[f=flv]rtmp://youtube.etc"
```

And that would stream to both.

I did find out that I needed "-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc" otherwise the encoder broke, complaining about malformed bits.

Any ideas?

The error is only with Facebook. YouTube works fine.

Console output:

```
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.72.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 1300 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.95.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 2000000/0/1300000 buffer size: 2048000 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (libfdk_aac), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.95.101 libfdk_aac
frame=   61 fps= 30 q=25.0 size=N/A time=00:00:01.97 bitrate=N/A speed=0.961x        
WriteN, RTMP send error 104 (136 bytes)
```

Comment: Show the complete console output from your command using tee muxer.

Comment: Try the tee command with `-flags +global_header` added.

Comment: Thank you, @Mulvya! If you provide that as an answer I can check it as the solution. What does it do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The FLV format requires global headers. When ffmpeg outputs to FLV directly `-f flv`, the encoder is signaled to produce global headers. But when `-f tee` is the primary/parent muxer, that flag isn't set. So, it has to be manually set via `-flags +global_header`.